# MySQL: Array comparsion

Tags: mysql, arrays

So, I have a clients table and tags table.
One client has many tags.
I want to select all clients, which have specific set of tags.
For example, let's select all clients, that have tags with id 1 and 9

```
SELECT clients.id from clients
INNER JOIN tags ON clients.id = tags.client_id
WHERE tags.id IN (1, 9)
GROUP BY clients.id
```

This does not work for me, because such query will return all clients that have 1, 9, or both 1 and 9

How can I return only such clients, that have both 1 and 9?

Comment: double join...?

Comment: @Jens: it is, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Show sample data

Comment: Karoly Horvath can you show an example? I have no idea how it works

Comment: @Jens: the real question is where *you* see it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using `HAVING`:

```
SELECT clients.id FROM clients
INNER JOIN tags ON clients.id = tags.client_id
WHERE tags.id IN (1, 9)
GROUP BY clients.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = 2
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e4d20/1/0

This query only returns the rows which have both (1 and 9 not 1 or 9) tags. If you change the number of tags on `IN` you have to change the number for the `HAVING` too.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you already accepted an answer, here is another variant:

```
SELECT clients.id 
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN tags ON clients.id = tags.client_id
WHERE tags.id IN (1, 9);
```

Comment: @LuninRoman You're welcome. Remember: if you begin with "_I want all clients..._", then `clients` is the "main" table on the LEFT and ALL its records will be displayed (filtered by `WHERE` clause if needed). And, when you continue with "_that have tags..._", then you JOIN the `tags` details to each record in it. So: the `tags` details will be JOIN-ed to the LEFT table.